# centercropping background image in android's constraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/something
    tools:context=".StartupActivity">

    <!--...some other view ...-->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

setting the background image with the `android:background` property does set the background of the image but it scales the image to fit the screen but I'd like to `centerCrop` the image to maintain its aspect ratio. How do I do that in the constraintLayout?(It has to be a constraintLayout since other views are already in place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in the layout it will adjust the image according to phone screen size..

Comment: actually this doesn't really work in ConstraintLayout at least, probably the property doesn't exist in ConstraintLayout